# Gedit Plugins: Loader "python" could not be found

Tags: python, gedit, plugins

I cloned some gedit plugins from github, created a gedit/plugins directory in the .local/share directory as directed by the author. When I tried to enable them, they were found, but I got an error message:

Gedit plugin could not be loaded: plugin loader "python" not found.

This is the repo:

https://github.com/nymanjens/gedit-improving-plugins

I am on ubuntu 20.04, and have aliased python=python3 in my .bashrc.

I also have anaconda installed and it has some path stuff in the bashrc which I thought might be the cause, but when I took it out, it made no difference.

I also commented out the alias in case that was the issue but still got the same error message.

Any ideas on how I enable this? The plugin loader has this:

```
[Plugin]
Loader=python
```

I have tried changing it from python to python3 but to no avail.

I did wonder if, because the repo is several years old, maybe it is a python2/3 issue, or maybe the plugins need to be in a different directory to be found correctly as gedit is ran from a shortcut on the dock.  If anyone knows of a plugin that does the same things as this plugin suite that I could use instead then pls let me know.  I wanted better syntax highlighting for python mainly - so it was more like atom syntax highlighting, and the line copying part.